# How to assign a unique id/name to a class for unserializing?

Tags: python, serialization

I want to assign a unique id/name to a class for unserialize. For example, give the following python dict:

```
data = [{"type": 1, "data": {"key": 333}}, {"type": 2, "data": {"foo": "bar"}]
```

I want to use the following code to unserialize the data:

```
class A(object):
    TYPE = 1
    def init_from_dict(self, dict_):
        pass

class B(object):
    TYPE = 2
    def init_from_dict(self, dict_):
        pass

factories = {A.TYPE: A, B.TYPE: B}

for dump in data:
    factory = factories[dump["type"]]
    object_ = factory()
    object_.init_from_dict(dump["data"])
```

The problem is there are other programmers writing the classes like `A` at the same time. They may assign a same `TYPE` to different classes. I thought about using uuid to represent a class. But it seems a little overkill. So I want to know if there are any better ways to assign a unique id/name to a class for unserializing?

Comment: Why each programmer do not namespace the classes he create ?

Comment: @shenshei It's the value of `TYPE` that matters, if two different classes like `A` and `B` have a same `TYPE` value `1`, then I can't automatically choose the right class from the `TYPE` value.

Comment: Yes but I do not understand why you want to do that instead of using python serialization tool like pickle.

Comment: @shenshei The data used for unserializing maybe generated by other tools and we want to control the format of it. It can be an json or xml file as well.

Comment: Ok, but I think that using TYPE attribute could be really error prone, I think  that having a dictionary mapping type with class to instantiate is a better choice.

Comment: @shenshei Agree. That's why I'm asking for a better way.